# Polynomial-time algorithm for Graph Isomorphism in case of Maximum Constrained Maximum Degree

Tags: graphs, graph-isomorphism

From [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsomorphicGraphs.html):

> A polynomial time algorithm is however known for planar graphs (Hopcroft and Tarjan 1973, Hopcroft and Wong 1974) and when the maximum vertex degree is bounded by a constant (Luks 1982; Skiena 1990, p. 181).

What are the running times of such algorithms, in terms of size of the graphs? What algorithms are used in practice for graph isomorphism?

Comment: The usual rule is one question per post.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the papers? They might state the running time.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithms used in practice differ a lot from theoretical algorithms. One popular software package is [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/). The link should also explain the algorithms used, which probably rely on combinatorial methods.

As for the running times for specific algorithms, they are likely stated in the papers. I suggest checking the references.